# How do I count occurrences of a specific element in a position in a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example,

```
a=[[a, 1], [b, 1], [1, 1]]
```

I want to find how many "1"s there are, but only those that are the second element in the nested lists. So it should give me 3, ignoring the "1" in the third list as it is the first element in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Use [***collections.Counter***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) subclass to count occurrences of any value:

```
import collections

a = [['a', 1], ['b', 1], [1, 1]]
counts = collections.Counter((l[1] for l in a))

print(counts[1])   # 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a generator and [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

```
>>> a = [['a', 1], ['b', 1], [1, 1]]
>>> sum(ele[1] == 1 for ele in a)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use:-

```
[item for sub_list in a[1:] for item in sub_list].count(1) # 3
```